# Tail Azure Blob Container log with Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, logging, azure-blob-storage

I am currently sinking application logging into a blob container. For every day there is a new log out put that in stored in a text file. Something like `today_date.txt`

Prior to sinking logs into blob we were logging into our VM and were able easily tail logs by Executing  `Get-Content -Path -Tail`.

Is it possible to tail logs in similar manner from azure container in blob storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly use this command `Get-Content -Path -Tail` for blob storage.

To do that, you should download the blob to local by using `Get-AzStorageBlobContent`, then use that command `Get-Content -Path -Tail`.

Another way is that you can use some third-party tools, which supports map blob container to local. Then you can directly use the command `Get-Content -Path -Tail`. **But most of the tools are not free**.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry I am no devops just a man wearing many hats in this company,  questions might be little off but, do I need to install any PS module in order to execute `Get-AzStorageBlobContent`? Once I get it does it sync up in real time?

Comment: @kkdeveloper7, yes, you need to install [Az.Storage module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az.Storage/3.1.0). Here is the doc about [azure powershell az module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-5.2.0). Since you download it locally, it will not sync up in real time. So once the blob is updated, you need to download it again.